# Como hacer un sort de 2 parametros

Tags: javascript

```
var painted_circles = [];
 painted_circles.push ["2-2", "4-4", "4-3", "2-5"];
el output: de menor a mayor["2-2", "2-5", "4-3", "4-4"]
```

Use el sort pero no hace la referencia.

Comment: `painted_circles .sort()`  funciona

Comment: painted_circles.sort(function(a, b){return b-a}); estaba haciendo esto, tienes razon. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Usa el sort() de javascript

```
var painted_circles = [];
painted_circles.push("2-2", "4-4", "4-3", "2-5");//Aquí es utilizar paréntesis
painted_circles.sort();
```